# Как в одном товаре прописать количество для размеров L,M,S

Tags: modx, revo

В магазине shopkeeper есть товары одежда есть `tv` параметры `price, inventory, gender, size`. Как в `tv size`  прописать так `L=3шт S=8шт M=2шт`, сразу для трёх размеров количество, и что бы это количество уменьшалось при покупки или отправке заказа покупателю. Мой вариант сделать три товара и в каждом товаре прописать

```
товар 1:size=L, inventory=3шт
товар 2:size=S, inventory=8шт
товар 3:size=M, inventory=2шт
```

и товар будет списываться и размер можно увидеть.
Но это мой вариант и он не очень понравится пользователю который будет вбивать все эти товары, как сделать так что бы из-за размеров не создавать дополнительные товары как прописать сразу все размеры в одном товаре? Подскажите хотя бы куда копать или кто то сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Как ни крути, но все равно создаются разные товары (даже в 1С при импользовании плана характеристик товара - все равно создается отдельные товары) - иначе как их потом учитывать? Здесь мне кажется, нада решать вопрос удобного интерфейса вбития товара - это и бесит пользователя.

Можно создать что-то типа выбираем, к примеру, футболку такой-то марки и предлагаем ему сразу все варианты размеров которые могут быть.

В общем подключаем фантазию, Объясняем пользователю, что по другому никак, но вот над интерфейсом можно поработать.

Answer (score 0):

Хранить сразу 3 значения в одной записи. L=3,S=8,M=2, сразу трёх размеров количество L+S+M.
При покупке смотреть какой размер купили и вычитать из этой колонки.